# Visual Studio 2019 + ReSharper intellisense not recognising null coalescing operator (??) in javascript

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2019, null-coalescing-operator, javascript-intellisense

Using Visual Studio 2019 with ReSharper (both on the latest version) I an unable to get intellisense to stop complaining about ECMAScript 2020 features like the null-coalescing operator (??).

The code works but it's annoying that the editor thinks it's an error. This is what I see:

[image: screenshot]

I've tried setting the project's TypeScript Build ECMAScript Version to ECMAScript 2020 in VS: the ReSharper ECMAScript version is set to "Experimental".  Has anyone managed to get this working?